# How to read, transpose, and stack rows based on whether a row value is the same across them

Tags: pandas

I have a raw dataset in an Excel spreadsheet that looks like this (snippet):

```
 SampleNbr   A     B     C    
       1     2.0   5.0   0.6  
       1     6.0   7.0   0.3
       2     9.2   4.0   0.5
       2     7.3   5.5   0.4
```

What I would like to do is convert this to something that looks like this:

```
A    2.0    9.2
B    5.0    4.0
C    0.6    0.5
A    6.0    7.3
B    7.0    5.5
C    0.3    0.4
```

In other words, where the sample number is the same, read the row values, transpose into a column, and stack them. It seems I need a mask to represent groups of rows where the sample number value is the same, but I'm not sure if I need to write a function to do the read, transpose, append.

Comment: is the answer i gave below useful for u?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
your_data = {
 'SampleNbr': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2},
 'A': {0: 2.0, 1: 6.0, 2: 9.2, 3: 7.3},
 'B': {0: 5.0, 1: 7.0, 2: 4.0, 3: 5.5},
 'C': {0: 0.6, 1: 0.3, 2: 0.5, 3: 0.4}
}

df = pd.DataFrame(your_data)

df['order'] = df.groupby('SampleNbr').cumcount()

df = (df
  .groupby(['order','SampleNbr'])['A','B','C'].sum()
  .stack(0)
  .unstack(1)
  .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
)

print(df)
SampleNbr   1   2
A   2.000   9.200
B   5.000   4.000
C   0.600   0.500
A   6.000   7.300
B   7.000   5.500
C   0.300   0.400
```